# How to fix "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip" warning in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to download zip file from JavaScript.
This is my code.

```
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = url
a.type = 'application/octet-stream'
a.download = ''

document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click()
document.body.removeChild(a)
```

I could download the file but I can see the folowing message as warning on Chrome DevTools console.

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip
```

How can I solve the warning?